# NSNotification object being sent is (null)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, nsnotificationcenter

When I receive data from a socket and pass the data to another VC via NSNotificationCenter, the passed object always logs (null), despite the object being present in the other class.

there is where I pass the data through.

UPDATED:

```
   -(void) initSIOSocket {
    [SIOSocket socketWithHost:@"http://192.168.1.4:8080" response:^(SIOSocket *socket) {

            self.socket = socket;
            NSLog(@"%@ from initSIOSocket", self.socket);

            [self.socket on:@"q_update_B" callback:^(NSArray *args) {


            NSArray *tracks = [args objectAtIndex:0];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"qUpdateB" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tracks forKey:@"tracksData"]];

        }];
```

..

```
- (void)receiveUpdateBNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Do parse respone data method and update yourTableViewData

    NSArray *tracks = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"tracksData"];
    NSLog(@"%@", tracks);
    self.tracks = tracks;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Console is STILL logging as (null) object. The notification is successful, no data is sent.

Comment: Can you try by initializing your tracks array like this: `NSArray *tracks = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[args objectAtIndex:0]];`. Because I suspect the tracks array is getting deallocated.

Comment: Still not working @AdilSoomro

Comment: Can you please try `NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", notification.userInfo);`

Answer (score 2):

For passing data using `NSNotification` you need to use the `userInfo` dictionary.

Post it like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"qUpdateB" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:tracks forKey:@"MyData"]];
```

And retrieve it using:

```
- (void)receiveUpdateBNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.tracks = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"MyData"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Object property is not intended for passing data.

> #### object
>
> The object associated with the notification. (read-only) Declaration
>
> `@property(readonly, retain) id object Discussion;`
>
> This is often the object that posted this notification. It may be nil.
>
> Typically you use this method to find out what object a notification
>   applies to when you receive a notification.
>
> For example, suppose you’ve registered an object to receive the
>   message handlePortDeath: when the “PortInvalid” notification is posted
>   to the notification center and that handlePortDeath: needs to access
>   the object monitoring the port that is now invalid. handlePortDeath:
>   can retrieve that object as shown here:
>
> ```
> - (void)handlePortDeath:(NSNotification *)notification
> {
>   ...
>   [self reclaimResourcesForPort:notification.object];
>   ...
> }
> ```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNotification/object)

Comment: hmm.. it is still null.

Comment: @Andy: check `tracks = [args objectAtIndex:0];` is null or not. Also if you are writing like that, you don't need to alloc init that variable

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How am I suppose to pass the data I receive from the socket on my Singleton to the viewcontroller AND reload the data when I receive an event?

Comment: @Andy: the current way is ok, also you can use KVO, since you have a singleton.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to use my Singleton to pass the data using the NSNotificationCenter, like so.

```
-(void) initSIOSocket {
    [SIOSocket socketWithHost:@"http://192.168.1.4:8080" response:^(SIOSocket *socket) {

            self.socket = socket;
            NSLog(@"%@ from initSIOSocket", self.socket);

            [self.socket on:@"q_update_B" callback:^(NSArray *args) {


            NSArray *tracks = [args objectAtIndex:0];
            self.setListTracks = tracks;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"qUpdateB" object:nil];

        }];


    }];

}
```

..

```
- (void)receiveUpdateBNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"qUpdateB"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
    // Do parse respone data method and update yourTableViewData
    NSArray *tracks = [[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance]setListTracks];
    self.tracks = tracks;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This is not what you need to do. There's no reason why you can pass the data along with the notification.

Comment: Can you provide an answer then please? I could not seem to be able to get my to pass through notification without being nil. Also,what is wrong with this method? @rmaddy

Comment: The other answer tells you the proper way. You just need to figure out why it isn't working for you.